# Java: Create method to print all multiples of 3 between 1 and n?

Tags: java

So the question is asking to create a method that will take an integer x as a parameter and print out all integers from 0->x that are multiples of three.

I can print out the number of times three divides x like so:

```
  public int Threes(int x){

    int i = 0;
    for(int counter = 1; counter <= x; counter++){
        if (counter % 3 ==0){
            i ++;
        }

    }
        return i;
```

but I'm not sure how to print out each multiple of 3!?

Comment: if (counter % 3 ==0){
            i ++; System.out.println(counter);
        }

Comment: That program does not print out the number of times three divides `x`.  Rather, that returns the number of multiples of `3` less than `x` FYI

Answer (score 7):

```
for(int counter = 1; counter <= x; counter++){
    if (counter % 3 ==0){
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

An even quicker approach would be to increment by 3

```
public void Threes(int x) {
    for (int counter = 3; counter <= x; counter = counter + 3) {
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

This loop will jump right to the multiples of 3, instead of counting every single number and having to do a modulo check for each iteration. Since we know that 1 and 2 are not multiples of 3, we just skip right to 3 at the beginning of the loop. If the input happens to be less than 3, then nothing will be printed. Also, the function should be `void` since you're printing instead of returning anything.

(Your title says `1 to n`, but your question says `0 to n`, so if you actually need from `0 to n`, then change the declaration of `counter` to `int counter = 0;`)

Answer (score 0):

Jason Aller wow that was so simple and elegant. This one builds on it by counting down from 300 to 3, by 3's.

```
public class byThrees {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int t = 100; t >= 0; t--) {
        System.out.println(t*3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Best practice using the For-loop in Java.

```
public class MultiplesOfThree {

    public static void main(String []args){
        for (int m = 1; m<=12; m++){
            System.out.println(m*3);
        }  
    }
}
```